# Hash removed from default routing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm writing an angular app where I need to accept an URL with a fragment hash (OAuth 2.0). Making it short it looks like this.

http://example.com/#access_token=918f4d6e90b25b13ef66a

When this URI is loaded, the routing process does not recognize the path and and it correctly redirects the app to the default route. The problem is that in thi way I loose the hash and I can't parse it anymore.

What I want to do is to parse the hash before it gets removed.
Do you have any idea on a possible solution?

Thanks.

P.S. In this app I can't use HTML5 mode. With it enabled it works just fine.

Comment: So, what exactly would like to happen ?

Comment: I would love to to be able to parse the hash before loosing it.

Comment: Obviously :) But what are you trying to achieve at a higher level ? How would you use that parsed token ?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a bug in this project[1]. I want to save the access token in a service so that I can use to to make some auth requests. 

[1] http://lelylan.github.io/lelylan-ng/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define an extra route to "catch" and save the access-token, before redirecting to another route.
E.g.:

```
$routeProvider
    ...
    .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
        template: '',
        controller: function ($location, $routeParams, AuthService) {
            AuthService.login(               // `AuthService` will save the token
                $routeParams.accessToken);   // The token is available in `$routeParams
                                             //     under the key `accessToken`
            $location.path('/');   // Redirect to the default route
            $location.replace();   // For better UX, remove this route from history
        }
    })
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/N8CgC/)**.

Or navigate directly to this URL for a live demo:
**http://fiddle.jshell.net/ExpertSystem/N8CgC/show#access_token=12345**.

Comment: Gonna try it tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot for your answer.